# Total nonlinear effect

Tags: r, regression

I'm been trying out the anova function in rms. I fit some restricted cubic spline on my continuous IVs in my mode and when I use the anova function on my lrm object I get a list of wald tests. I'm curious as to how the total nonlinear test is obtained?

Example taken from the package itself:

```
n <- 1000    # define sample size
treat <- factor(sample(c('a','b','c'), n,TRUE))
num.diseases <- sample(0:4, n,TRUE)
age <- rnorm(n, 50, 10)
cholesterol <- rnorm(n, 200, 25)
weight <- rnorm(n, 150, 20)
sex <- factor(sample(c('female','male'), n,TRUE))
label(age) <- 'Age'      # label is in Hmisc
label(num.diseases) <- 'Number of Comorbid Diseases'
label(cholesterol) <- 'Total Cholesterol'
label(weight) <- 'Weight, lbs.'
label(sex) <- 'Sex'
units(cholesterol) <- 'mg/dl'   # uses units.default in Hmisc


# Specify population model for log odds that Y=1
L <- .1*(num.diseases-2) + .045*(age-50) +
 (log(cholesterol - 10)-5.2)*(-2*(treat=='a') +
 3.5*(treat=='b')+2*(treat=='c'))
# Simulate binary y to have Prob(y=1) = 1/[1+exp(-L)]
y <- ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0)


fit <- lrm(y ~ treat + rcs(age) + rcs(cholesterol))
a <- anova(fit)               
            Wald Statistics          Response: y 
Factor          Chi-Square d.f. P     
treat            4.27       2   0.1185
age             22.30       4   0.0002
Nonlinear       0.64       3   0.8861
cholesterol     12.44       4   0.0144
Nonlinear       6.72       3   0.0814
TOTAL NONLINEAR  7.46       6   0.2804
TOTAL           36.97      10   0.0001
```

What is the statistics for the total nonlinear term here?

Comment: You'll make it easier for people to help you if you provide an example, preferably a reproducible one.

Comment: I've added an example now.

Comment: It's for the test of the 6 non-linear terms (3 non-linear age terms and 3 non-linear cholesterol terms) as a whole. That is, it compares the fitted model with the model that only has linear terms, which would be specified as `lrm(y ~ treat + age + cholesterol)`.